# stencil is not rerendeing component when @state() decorated property is changed

Tags: stenciljs

I started with stencil today. Following code is all I have in my project. [Docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/state/#state-decorator) say, if Component member decorated with `@state()` is changed, component will rerender.

> Any changes to a @State() property will cause the components render function to be called again.

But even this simple thing is not working. Pls advice.

```
import {Component, State} from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {

  @State() name:string = 'john';

  changeName(){
    this.name = "Peter";
    console.log('inside changeName');
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <p>{this.name}</p>
      <button onClick={this.changeName}>click</button>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

When I click on the button `inside changeName` is logged but no changes to `name` is seen in view.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try changing your onClick to an arrow function:

```
<button onClick={() => this.changeName()}>click</button>
```

This preserves the meaning of `this` to reference your class. See https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx/#handling-user-input for more details and examples.

Answer (score 3):

@matthewsteele answer is right but you can also define your function like below to make it work.

```
private changeName = () => {
  this.name = "Peter";
  console.log('inside changeName');
}
```

Doing above the this reference will still preserves to the class.